# Take input from text file into a pl/sql script

Tags: unix, plsql

I have a text file and a PL/SQL script both present in the same Unix server at same location. I want to take input from the text file into that PL/SQL script.
Text File contents:

```
a.txt
b.csv
c.ext
```

PL/SQL script:

```
select status from table where file_name=''-- the file name should come from text file contents
if status ='REQUEST' then
delete from table where file_name ='' --  the same file which is mentioned above
else
if status ='SUCCESS' then
flag=0;
/
```

Now, I want to take the flag value to the shell script.
I hope it is more clear now. Please help.

Comment: Is the opening/reading/parsing of the text file already implemented in the script? Can you just use a command line argument? What is the intended output? Please clarify your question. Also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: If the text file is composed of records you will be reading, you could load it into a table using `sqlldr` first, then access it via SQL. Of course an external table would work too. At any rate please add more info for more targeted help.

Comment: I have modified the query. can you please check again?

Comment: Note that for PL/SQL to be able to read the file, that file has to be on the database server or a drive accessible to it. That is, the database has to be able to see the file.

Answer (score 1):

https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/utl_file-random-access-of-files-9i
refer this tutorial.
read the data into a varchar2 variable and then do strin manipulation in that text data.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of external tables.  In a nutshell, you would create a database object that lets you access a flatfile like a table.  See here for an introduction: http://allthingsoracle.com/external-tables-an-introduction/.